# Gson parsing fails when the JSON contains string or jsonobject for a key

Tags: android, json

In my Android app, I got a response from the web service. The web service returns the response as

```
{
  "Result": -1,
  "Message": "E-mail/Mobile number or password is wrong, make sure your Mobile Number is entered with country code.",
  "MessageType": 2,
  "ResponseData": ""
}
```

in case of failure due to wrong credentials.

In success case, it returns as follows

```
{
  "Result": -1,
  "Message": "E-mail/Mobile number or password is wrong, make sure your Mobile Number is entered with country code.",
  "MessageType": 2,
  "ResponseData": {...}
}
```

That is, for the "ResponseData", the value is either string or JSONObject.

I'm using Gson for parsing.

I wrote the POJO class for parsing

```
    public class LoginResponse {
        @SerializedName("Result")
        @Expose
        private Integer result;
        @SerializedName("Message")
        @Expose
        private String message;
        @SerializedName("MessageType")
        @Expose
        private Integer messageType;
        @SerializedName("ResponseData")
        @Expose
        private ResponseData responseData;
 public class ResponseData {
...
}

    }
```

The ResponseData is the inner class of LoginResponse.

When parsing using gson:

```
gsonObject.fromJson(decodeString(response.body().getOutput()), LoginResponse.class);
```

It gives me the error: **com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 5 column 20 path**

how to handle this?

**Note:** The decodeString() method gives the above specified json object.

Comment: `decodeString(response.body().getOutput()` what is the output of this part? use Log/Debug to get it

Comment: your response is a JSON Object, are you treating it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple types for one key `responseData` in your responses it can be either `String` or `ResponseData` but your class can only accept `ResponseData`.

I'd suggest returning null instead of an empty string then you can check if `responseData == null`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a String and a JSONObject at the same place (key):
"ResponseData": ""
"ResponseData": {...}

You can either use JsonNull for error and object when success, or better - define a new key that will show you if there is an error.